# How to add a github library to gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I made a android library in github that i want to add to Gradle,
that other people can add 
compile "my project ..." 
to there android build.
how can i upload it to Gradle?

(I didn't find an answer for this anywhere)

**EDIT:**
To clear my question, I want to release a library for developers.

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand the question, are you trying to convert a project from eclipse to Gradle?

Comment: no, i have a project that i want to release as a library for developers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't "upload a library to gradle" ;-), you make it accessibla via gradle, so you first have to compile your library and publish the generated artefacts (aar or jar files) to a central repository, like Maven Central.

There are two common Maven repositories at time of this writing:

- Maven Central http://search.maven.org/
- JCenter https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter

See this guide as a direction for mavenCentral:

http://www.vandalsoftware.com/post/52468430435/publishing-an-android-library-aar-to-a-maven

Since recent Android Studio versions, JCenter is the preferred default repository, so you may register there and upload your archives to it, like explained here:

https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/

Hope that helps.

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
won't work...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to expose your library to other developers is by using the [JitPack](http://jitpack.io) service.

The requirement is that you create a GitHub release and that you have a build file in your repository. It doesn't require that you upload your library.